# Using VBA cut cell text and format with double click then paste with next click

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to set up so a double click in a cell cuts text AND formatting and then a single click in another cell paste the cut text AND format.  Current code only paste un-formatted text into new cell.

here is what I have now

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim CutValue
    Dim CutCell As Range

    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

        Cancel = True
        Target.Cut 
        CutValue = Target.Text
        Set CutCell = Target

    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Not IsEmpty(CutValue) Then
            Target.FormulaR1C1 = CutValue
            CutValue = Empty
            CutCell.Clear
        End If

    End Sub
```

Big thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the cut until the user selects another cell:

```
Option Explicit

Dim CutCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = True
    Set CutCell = Target

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not CutCell Is Nothing Then
        CutCell.Cut Target.Cells(1) '<<<in case of multi-cell selection...
        Set CutCell = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```